# sql multiple counts

Tags: sql, count

I have two queries that perform counts.  One is a total count and the next is a total count for the number of test cases that have passed.

I would like to write one query for this (have one result set).  How is it possible that I can return a table that returns the following

```
|Release Name| Total Count | Passed


SELECT
REL.REL_NAME as "Release Name",
count(REL.REL_NAME) as "Total Count"
FROM TEST TST
INNER JOIN TESTCYCL TCY ON TST.TS_TEST_ID = TCY.TC_TEST_ID
INNER JOIN CYCLE CYC ON TCY.TC_CYCLE_ID = CYC.CY_CYCLE_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES RCY ON CYC.CY_ASSIGN_RCYC = RCY.RCYC_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASES REL ON REL.REL_ID = RCY.RCYC_PARENT_ID
GROUP BY REL.REL_NAME
ORDER BY REL.REL_NAME

SELECT
REL.REL_NAME as "Release Name",
count(REL.REL_NAME) as "Passed"
FROM TEST TST
INNER JOIN TESTCYCL TCY ON TST.TS_TEST_ID = TCY.TC_TEST_ID
INNER JOIN CYCLE CYC ON TCY.TC_CYCLE_ID = CYC.CY_CYCLE_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES RCY ON CYC.CY_ASSIGN_RCYC = RCY.RCYC_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASES REL ON REL.REL_ID = RCY.RCYC_PARENT_ID
WHERE TC_STATUS = 'Passed'
GROUP BY REL.REL_NAME
ORDER BY REL.REL_NAME`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you both results:

```
SELECT
REL.REL_NAME as "Release Name",
count(REL.REL_NAME) as "Total Count"
sum(case when TC_STATUS = 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) as "Passed"
FROM TEST TST
INNER JOIN TESTCYCL TCY ON TST.TS_TEST_ID = TCY.TC_TEST_ID
INNER JOIN CYCLE CYC ON TCY.TC_CYCLE_ID = CYC.CY_CYCLE_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES RCY ON CYC.CY_ASSIGN_RCYC = RCY.RCYC_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASES REL ON REL.REL_ID = RCY.RCYC_PARENT_ID

GROUP BY REL.REL_NAME
ORDER BY REL.REL_NAME`
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
REL.REL_NAME as "Release Name",
COUNT(REL.REL_NAME) as "Total Count",
COUNT(CASE WHEN TC_STATUS = 'Passed' THEN REL.REL_NAME END) as "Passed"
FROM TEST TST
INNER JOIN TESTCYCL TCY ON TST.TS_TEST_ID = TCY.TC_TEST_ID
INNER JOIN CYCLE CYC ON TCY.TC_CYCLE_ID = CYC.CY_CYCLE_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES RCY ON CYC.CY_ASSIGN_RCYC = RCY.RCYC_ID
INNER JOIN RELEASES REL ON REL.REL_ID = RCY.RCYC_PARENT_ID
GROUP BY REL.REL_NAME
ORDER BY REL.REL_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for something like this..

--SAMPLE TABLES--

```
create table rel
(
tst_id int,
Release_Name varchar(50)
);


insert into rel values
(1,'Jan_Release'),
(2,'Feb_Release'),
(3,'Mar_Release'),
(2,'Mar_Release'),
(1,'Feb_Release');

create table tst
(
tst_id int,
tc_status varchar(50)
);

insert into tst values
(1,'Pass'),
(2,'Fail'),
(3,'Pass');
```

--SAMPLE DATA--

[image: rel Table]

[image: tst Table]

--Query Used--

```
select 
rel.Release_Name,
count(rel.Release_Name) as Total_Count,
sum(case when tst.tc_status = 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as "Passed"
from rel
inner join tst on rel.tst_id=tst.tst_id
group by rel.release_name
order by rel.release_name;
```

--Result Set--

[image: Result Set]